# Possible tool to parse the date-formatting of a string?

Tags: python, date, strptime

I find myself often looking for ways to figure out what format a date has, for example:

[image]

Is it `d` or `dd` or `D` or `m` or `mm` or `mmm`, etc. Then I usually go to something like http://strftime.net/ and then use python with some trial-and-error. Is there a more straightforward way to figure out the format of a date string? I'm hoping there's something like  those tools for [urlencoding](https://www.urlencoder.org/) or font-determiner https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ where you can just paste in the string and it'll parse the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`dateinfer`](https://github.com/jeffreystarr/dateinfer)  as a start:

```
>>> dateinfer.infer(['27-Feb-18'])
'%d-%b-%H'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks as though `dateparser` is another candidate to consider.

```
import dateparser

dateparser.parse('27-Feb-18')
# datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 27, 0, 0)
```

https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: thanks, how would that be used with the given input date?

Comment: @David542, I added your example to my answer. You may wish to edit your post to show your test input as text and not via a link to an image - at first I didn't even realize you had an example in mind.

Comment: oh, this parses the date, but `dateparser` doesn't retain an intermediate state where it shows the actual format -- for example, this doesn't show `%d-%b-%H` which is what I want to find.